# Rendering text with SDL2 and OpenGL

Tags: opengl, sdl, sdl2

I've been trying to have text rendering in my OpenGL scene using SDL2. The tutorial I came across is this one [Rendering text](http://headerphile.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/sdl2-part-10-text-rendering.html)

I followed the same code, and I get text rendering fine. However the issue I'm having is that there is obviously a "conflict" between the OpenGL rendering and the `SDL_Renderer` used in the code. When I run my scene the text displays but everything else keeps flickering. The following gif shows the issue:

[image]

Any idea on how to overcome this while still just using `SDL2` and `OpenGL`, not another library or anything.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if there is a solution that doesn't include creating an OpenGL texture and moving the SDL2_ttf created SDL_Surface into it.

Comment: If you cut/pasted from two different tutorials, make sure you're not calling both SDL_RenderPresent() and wglSwapBuffers().

Comment: Minimal SDL + OpenGL example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061276/how-to-draw-a-triangle-with-sdl2-and-opengl/40824828#40824828 then add the text specifics from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847899/how-to-draw-text-using-only-opengl-methods/36065835#36065835

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem using SDL_Renderer with OpenGL. You can save the text to a Surface, and then use this example: http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tip-sdl-surface-to-opengl-texture